# Placing figure inside itemize environment with text floating around it

Tags: beamer, floats, itemize, wrapfigure

I want to creat a slide with a logo at the right and the logo is supposed to start with item one in an itemize environment and extend down to item three. This is what I have:

[image]

I used `floatflt` for this, but the figure starts in the frame title and does not go into the first three items.

The following is a minimal example (without `beamer` loaded):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatflt,graphicx}

\begin{document}

{Organisation und Softwareentwicklung für OA-Bücher}

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{Logo_LSP_blau}
   \end{floatingfigure}


Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text ySome text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 

\begin{itemize}
\item 
%% \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
%%  \vspace{-16pt}
%%  \centering 
%%  \includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{Logo_LSP_blau}
%%  \vspace{-10pt}
%% \end{wrapfigure}
Verlag: Language Science Press% \hfill\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{Logo_LSP_blau}
\item International organisierte community
\item dezentral organisierte Buchreihen (zur Zeit 17)
\item 32 Einreichungen, 4 Ablehnungen, 24 angenommen, 9 veröffentlicht
\item Qualitätssicherung durch peer review und optinal open review

\bigskip


\item Erweiterung und Anpassung der Software (Open Monograph Press)

\item Konversion von \LaTeX{} in andere Formate ePub, XML, \ldots

\item Gamification
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume the lower boundary of the image should be at the first `\item` line, not the top boundary? The `\label` is useless without `\caption`

Comment: The top boundary should be at the top boundary of the first itme line and the fiure should span the first three items. So the bottom of the figure may be at the bottom of item three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For preparing slides, the `beamer` class is typically being used. To place the image on the right place without interference with `itemize`, one can use the `tikzmark` library from `tikz` package. At the end of the phrase **(zur Zeit 17)** in the third `\item`, we set a `\tikzmark{bottom}` to which we refer afterwards when placing the image.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Organisation und Softwareentwicklung für OA-Bücher}
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text ySome text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 

\begin{itemize}
\item Verlag: Language Science Press
\item International organisierte community
\item dezentral organisierte Buchreihen (zur Zeit 17)\tikzmark{bottom}
\item 32 Einreichungen, 4 Ablehnungen, 24 angenommen, 9 veröffentlicht
\item Qualitätssicherung durch peer review und optinal open review

\bigskip
\item Erweiterung und Anpassung der Software (Open Monograph Press)
\item Konversion von \LaTeX{} in andere Formate ePub, XML, \ldots
\item Gamification
\end{itemize}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\node at({pic cs:bottom})[anchor=south west,yshift=-.7ex]{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{Logo_LSP_blau}};}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much! I have `\pause`commands after the items. This has the effect that I see the logo only after I uncovered the third item. I tried to put it into `\visible<1->`but this did not work.

Comment: Got it: placed the `\tikzmark` command at the first item, put the `\tikz` command after it and positioned the image accordingly. Thanks a lot!